# C# WinForms crashes with no Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, crash, httpclient

I have a C# WinForms application.

I'm using the Unity Container nuget package to inject my service classes. If I get the service class in the `Program.cs` and make a call to my web api to authenticate a username and password using odata, it works successfully. If I call `Application.Run(myForm)`, where `myForm` is a Telerik RadForm, and asynchronously run the same call, the application closes with no exceptions thrown.

I am using `Application.ThreadException` and registering `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)` but this does not catch anything.

The line that is causing the application to crash is a call to `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync()`. This call is made from within the service class located in a separate `.Net Standard 2.0 Class Library`. The main application is a `.NET Framework 4.7.2 Windows Application` and the UI controls are located in a `.NET Framework 4.7.2 Class Library`. Again, this call is successful if called outside of the Telerik RadForm.

From within the Telerik RadForm I have tried to execute the call using:

- `private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)`
- `var t = new Thread(() => Runner.DoWork(new Credentials(u, p, CLIENT_ID)))`
- An asynchronous call to a static method without using `await`

I did get a different result when I called `LoginAsync(...).Result` on the service class. This caused the application to enter a thread lock state, but did not crash the app.

**UPDATE:**

There are two RadForms; a `DashboardForm` and a `LoginForm`. `Program.cs` launches the Dashboard which checks for an existing Bearer token. If the token does not exist, the Dashboard displays the Login using `.ShowDialog()` to prevent using the Dashboard until authenticated. The Login then uses the service class described above.

If instead of launching the Dashboard in `Program.cs` using `Application.Run()` I launch the Login, the service call to authenticate is successful.

I then tried launching the Login, from the Dashboard in a new thread, but this resulted in the same problem described above.

Why does the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync()` crash the application (with no exceptions) if it is called from a Form displayed by another Form?

**Program**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        WinInjectionHelper.Register(UnityConfig.RegisterComponents);

        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        Application.Run(new DashboardForm());
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Big error...");
    }
```

**Dashboard**

```
public partial class DashboardForm : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm, IDashboard
{
    private readonly IProductService _service;

    public DashboardForm()
    {
        this._service = WinInjectionHelper.Generate2<IProductService>();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DashboardForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.NotAuthenticated())
        {
            var frm = new LoginForm();

            if (frm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: display error to user
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Login**

```
public partial class LoginForm : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    private const string CLIENT_ID = "...";
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _service;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        this._service = WinInjectionHelper.Generate2<IAuthenticationService>();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }

    private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var u = this.txtUsername.Text.Trim();
        var p = this.txtPassword.Text.Trim();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is required!", "NOTICE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password is required!", "NOTICE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var jwt = await this._service.LoginAsync(new Credentials(u, p, CLIENT_ID));

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, u),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, u),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes2.AccessToken, jwt.AccessToken),
            }, "JWT");

            ((GenericPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).AddIdentity(identity);

            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while processing your request.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First do not open forms on new threads, that's just asking for trouble. Please post a [MRE] to show exactly what code is in use and causing the issue.

Comment: Like JSteward said, anything UI related that's done on any thread but the main thread will crash your application. As for why you get no exception, Exceptions thrown in methods that return a Task won't bubble up unless you're using await or wait.

Comment: OP, if at all possible, you should avoid creating threads or using the `Thread` class. The more modern (and much easier) way to handle this is with Tasks and async/wait.

Comment: As I stated, the first thing was attempted was using as async method call (all the way up the stack) and every layer is wrapped in a try/catch. There is no reason an exception would not be caught, yet no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by calling the Login form first and then displaying the Dashboard before closing the Login and changed `program.cs` so that closing the Login did not exit the application. This does require calling `Application.Exit()` when the application does need to close.

**Program**

```
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        ...

        new LoginForm().Show();

        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Windows Event Viewer and look under application to find the crash logs.  I had the same issue with an application I was working on and this was the only place that had any information on it. It actually helped me resolve the issue which was related to targeting a specific .NET Framework version. Click on the bottom left Window button and type in "event viewer" in there an then click on the icon that shows up.

Easiest way to do it is to run the application and have it crash and then immediately go to event viewer so it will be at the top of the list.

Comment: There are none. This was the first place I looked.